# mipmapping enabled without a complete mip-chain

Tags: ios, opengl-es, mipmaps

The following is my `create texture` function:

```
- (GLuint)setupTexture:(NSString *)fileName {

    // 1
    CGImageRef spriteImage = [UIImage imageNamed:fileName].CGImage;
    if (!spriteImage) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to load image %@", fileName);
        exit(1);
    }

    // 2
    size_t kWidth = CGImageGetWidth(spriteImage);
    size_t kHeight = CGImageGetHeight(spriteImage);

    // 3
    GLubyte * spriteData = (GLubyte *) calloc(kWidth*kHeight*4, sizeof(GLubyte));

    // 4
    GLuint texName;
    glGenTextures(1, &texName);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texName);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_BGRA, (int)kWidth, (int)kHeight, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, spriteData);
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    //glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL_APPLE, 0);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    return texName;
}
```

I use GPU capture in XCode, and find an error like this:

[image]

I'm new to OpenGL, how can I solve this? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at texture descriptor number in the screenshot, 391341552. It's very unlikely to have this many textures in a single process.
It seems like the issue stems not in the set-up, but rather in texture binding before drawing.

Usually, after you successfully set up your textures and vertex arrays, you draw them as follows:

```
glUseProgram(programDescriptor);
glBindVertexArray(vertexArrayDescriptor);
glUniform(...);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureDescriptor);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, verticesQuantity);
```

Perhaps you passed some pointer in `glBindTexture`?